# Function got in cycle (repeats itself) instead of working just one time

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I create GameObject near the other object. Function "Instantiate" repeats itself (gets in cycle) and that's the problem. I need it to be called just one time.

I've tried:
 1. calling function pressing the button (GetKey). Still this function creates 3-4 objects.
 2. adding the code in Update and FixedUpdate. And still it creates several objects. :(

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class table : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject obj;
public Renderer rend;

void Start () {

    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    Vector3 center = rend.bounds.center;
    Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3 (12,0,0);

    Instantiate (obj, pos, Quaternion.identity);

}

}
```

[okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5VRp.jpg)

[Not okay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgQLa.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `Instantiate (obj, pos, Quaternion.identity);` in your `Start` method. Your script *table* is attached to the `GameObject` that you are instantiating, that means that it will call the `Start` method each time the `GameObject` is spawned, which will create a new one with a new script and call that `Start` method of that script.

> Possible solutions:
>   1. Move the line `Instantiate (obj, pos, Quaternion.identity);` to a method/function and call that function upon request
> 2. Remove the script *table* from your `Prefab` (in your case it's called *obj* in the script).